# Creating a new link to python3 and renaming it to python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I just started using django. 
OS I'm using: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I created a virtual environment named mydjangoblog and i installed there django. By default it has python2 inside the folder mydjangoblog/bin
I prefer that django use python3 rather than python2. HOw can I manage it?

I discovered that when I type "python" inside the terminal python2 opens. This is because The python link points to python2 according to the PEP.

[this is the content of the bin folder of the virtual environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgwGM.png)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: "My problem is that it uses by default python 2 which is installed in my Comupetr"—not exactly. It uses the Python from the environment in which you install it. Create a virtual environment using Python 3 and install Django there. This is likely a much better idea (and if your OS comes with Python a much _safer_ idea) than changing your default Python. It also has the benefit of not polluting your global Python package space.

Comment: This explains how to install to a non-default python version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/10366273

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: OS I'm using:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I created a virtual environment named mydjangoblog and i installed there django. By default it has python2 inside the folder mydjangoblog/bin

Comment: When creating the virtualenv, use `-p path_to_python3`